# How does the ImageExposureCombine function work?

Tags: image-processing, reference-request

Any ideas for how to find out how this function works?

[image]

> Combines differently exposed images of the same scene into a single image with overall good exposure.

I'm writing a physics paper that involves this function in some code. 
I cannot explain how this function works mathematically.

The act of combining differently exposed images seems like a common task in image processing.

If you can point me to a paper that gives a mathematical description of what this function may be doing or if you know of a similar function in an open source language that would help me greatly.

Comment: You will need to ask Wolfram Support.

Comment: The code for this function can be inspected using ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[ImageExposureCombine]``. You will see that it calls the OpenCV function corresponding to the options given, for example [MergeRobertson](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/hdr_imaging.html#rb99). There are some references given in the OpenCV documentation.